# Application Error : This version of the application is not configured for Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, apk

I got this error message while I was testing my in app billing with android IAB v3
while I started my purchase flow. And I saw this message after going into the google play store.

I have read through all the other posts which were post in here about this error.

All the suggested answers are something like making the versionCode the same between the testing apk in my device and the upload apk in the google developer console. And upload a sign APK into google play.

I have done all of these and already waited for half day long. But I still get this error now.
I have no idea what I can do to fix it.

Please give me some suggestions. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Is your application signed with debug key while this error happens?

Comment: how can I check is that a debug key or not? I think I havent made any change of this and just using the default value given by Eclipse.

Comment: Does it mean I should upload a non-debug one to google and use it to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing your application directly installing from eclipse and you didn't set up to sign automatically with another keystore than it's in debug mode. If your application is release on market and you are testing your app with real in-app products your app won't work until you signed it up with the same keystore which you were using while uploading to Google Play Store. In debug mode you can test your in-app implementation using android test products.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I just found that I only installed the debug version into my device. After I reinstall with an sign export apk from Eclipse manually, I can get into my real in app product finally.
By the way, I think it is rather troublesome that I need to manually install an apk into my testing device.

Comment: You can setup your eclipse to sign your apk with your keystore everytime you are building a new apk from eclipse. in this way you won't need to install it manually